# Jsoup cleaner not removing the elements

Tags: java, jsoup

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(html2);
Whitelist whitelist = new Whitelist();
Whitelist.simpleText().addTags("table","td", "tr","tbody");
Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whitelist);
cleaner.clean(doc);

Elements gradesTableBody = doc.select(".user-grade").select("tbody").select("tr");
Log.d("output", gradesTableBody.html());
```

the output html still contains `<img>` tags etc. the cleaner does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cleaner.clean` returns a *new* document (which you currently just throw away).

You need to do

```
doc = cleaner.clean(doc);
^^^^^
```

Also, these lines doesn't make sense:

```
Whitelist whitelist = new Whitelist();
Whitelist.simpleText().addTags("table","td", "tr","tbody");
```

I think you may want to do

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.simpleText().addTags("table","td", "tr","tbody");
```